# where can I find the documentation for the apple's Darwin API

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, darwin

where can I find the documentation for the apple's Darwin API?

such as `mach_task_basic_info` `mach_msg_type_number_t`and so on.

I find many documentations of apple's Darwin API is empty on the developer.apple.com

Comment: are you talking about Darwin Notification Api?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya No

Answer (score 0):

Generally these kinds of things are only documented in the header files. For example, `mach_task_basic_info` is documented in task_info.h. You can find all the header files in the /usr/include/mach directory inside the SDK:

```
ls $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/mach
```

The amount of documentation in the headers varies a lot. There may be extensive, detailed docs, or there might just be the struct fields. However, this is generally the most accurate information available.

Some more general information is available in the [Mach Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html) of the Kernel Programming Guide, but it does not provide the kind of symbol-specific documentation you're asking about.